# how to add other (input text option) in a javascript quiz page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed a quiz page where Each question has to load in separate page with options (click-type), certain questions will have more than one answer with Others option as well. At the end of the questionnaire, the user must fill-up the form. Option to review all the answers/info finally before submit.

I want to add other (input text option) in some questions but i am not able to add this.
I have attached my code, please have a look and give me some advice

```js
(function() {
    var questions = [{
        question: "Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?",
        choices:[ "yes",
"No"],
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*9?",
        choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "What is 1*7?",
        choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*8?",
        choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
        correctAnswer: 4
    }];

    var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
    var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
    var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

    // Display initial question
    displayNext();

    // Click handler for the 'next' button
    $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Suspend click listener during fade animation
        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        choose();

        // If no user selection, progress is stopped
        if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
            alert('Please make a selection!');
        } else {
            questionCounter++;
            displayNext();
        }
    });

    // Click handler for the 'prev' button
    $('#prev').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        choose();
        questionCounter--;
        displayNext();
    });

    // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
    $('#start').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        questionCounter = 0;
        selections = [];
        displayNext();
        $('#start').hide();
    });

    // Animates buttons on hover
    $('.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.button').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
    // the answer selections
    function createQuestionElement(index) {
        var qElement = $('<div>', {
            id: 'question'
        });

        var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
        qElement.append(header);

        var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
        qElement.append(question);

        var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
        qElement.append(radioButtons);

        return qElement;
    }

    // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
    function createRadios(index) {
        var radioList = $('<ul>');
        var item;
        var input = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
            item = $('<li>');
            input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
            input += questions[index].choices[i];
            item.append(input);
            radioList.append(item);
        }
        return radioList;
    }

    // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
    function choose() {
        selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    }

    // Displays next requested element
    function displayNext() {
        quiz.fadeOut(function() {
            $('#question').remove();

            if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
                var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
                quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
                if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
                    $('input[value=' + selections[questionCounter] + ']').prop('checked', true);
                }

                // Controls display of 'prev' button
                if (questionCounter === 1) {
                    $('#prev').show();
                } else if (questionCounter === 0) {

                    $('#prev').hide();
                    $('#next').show();
                }
            } else {
                var scoreElem = displayScore();
                quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
                $('#next').hide();
                $('#prev').hide();
                $('#start').show();
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

```css
    
    CSS INDEX
    ===================
 
    1. Theme Default CSS (body, link color, section etc)
    2. Header Area
    3. Slider Area
    4. Feature Area
    5. Service Area
    6. Video Area
    7. Features Carousel Area
    8. Pricing Area
    9. Clients Area
    10. Blog Area
    11. Download Area
    12. Contact Area
    13. Footer Area
    14. Image, Solid, Gradient, Transparent, Video Background Area
    15. Light Section Style
    16. Layout Two Style
    17. Scroll Up Start
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*----------------------------------------*/
/*  1. Theme default CSS
/*----------------------------------------*/
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html, body {height: 100%;}
.floatleft {float:left !important;}
.floatright {float:right !important;}
.floatnone {float:none !important;}
.alignleft {text-align:left !important;}
.alignright {text-align:right !important;}
.aligncenter {text-align:center !important;}
.no-display { display:none; }
.no-margin { margin:0 !important; }
.no-padding { padding:0 !important; }
a:focus, button:focus {outline:0px solid}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
.fix {overflow:hidden}
p {
    font-family: "Neuton",serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
a {transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active, a:hover, a:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none
}
ul{
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.clear{clear:both}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.browserupgrade {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}
body {
  color: #D0D0D0;
  font-family: "montserratregular";
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
#header {
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
#logo{
 clear:both;
 margin:20px;
}
#logo a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: -18px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <title>Security Simplified</title>
 
 <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" >

    <!-- Theme Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
 
</head>
<body class="no-transition stretched">

<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<header id="header" class="full-header">

     <!-- Logo-->
     <div id="logo">
      <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo"><img src="images/sequreone-logo.png" alt="Secqureone Logo"></a>
     </div><!-- #logo end -->
</header>   

<div id='quiz'></div>
            <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
            <!-- <button class='' id='next'>Next</a></button>
                <button class='' id='prev'>Prev</a></button>
                <button class='' id='start'> Start Over</a></button> -->
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

</div> <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

Please help me to add input text option in questions

Comment: add property for your array of obj called question mode 
that has 2 values , radio and text  
and based on it decide what option to create dynamically

Comment: could you please help me with some working example

Answer (score 0):

try replacing with this:

```
var questions = [{
        question: "Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?",
        choices:[ "yes","No","Others"],
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*9?",
        choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156,"Others"],
        correctAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "What is 1*7?",
        choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8,"Others"],
        correctAnswer: 3
    }, {
        question: "What is 8*8?",
        choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64,"Others"],
        correctAnswer: 4
    }];
```

Comment: after click on other there should be a text box for user input. could you please help me to achieve this target

Answer (score 0):

I've added another item to questions array and modified createRadios() function 
so edit your code with this modification and tell me what happened

```
var questions = [{
    question: "Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?",
    choices:[ "yes",
"No"], 
    questionMode: 2
}, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0,
    questionMode: 2
}, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3,
    questionMode: 2
}, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4,
    questionMode: 2
},{
    question: "What is your name?",
    choices: null,
    questionMode: 1
}];


function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
if(questions[index].questionMode === 2)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
        item = $('<li>');
        input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
        input += questions[index].choices[i];
        item.append(input);
        radioList.append(item);
    }
 }
 else (questions[index].questionMode === 1)
{
 item = $('<li>');
        input = questions[index].choices[i];
        input += '<input type="text" name="answer"/>';
        item.append(input);
        radioList.append(item);
}
    return radioList;
}
```

Comment: hi mahmoud, i want to add input box once user click on other option. so that he/ she can add own ansere. so could you please help me to achieve this .

Comment: so u need to add textbox as optional answer and other options

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var others="Others<input type='text' />";
    (function() {
        var questions = [{
            question: "Does Your Business have IT Security Policies and Procedures?",
            choices:[ "yes","No",others],
        }, {
            question: "What is 8*9?",
            choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156,others],
            correctAnswer: 0
        }, {
            question: "What is 1*7?",
            choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8,others],
            correctAnswer: 3
        }, {
            question: "What is 8*8?",
            choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64,others],
            correctAnswer: 4
        }]
```

now that text fields are there you need to add some javascript to get their values. I assume you can resume things from there